# Multivariate Fisher noncentral hypergeometric distribution relationship to probabilities

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_noncentral_hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_distribution) the probability mass function of the multivariate Fisher noncentral hypergeometric distribution with parameters $c\in\mathbb{N}$ (number of colors), $\vec{m}\in\mathbb{N}^c$ (number of elements per color), $n\in\{0,\ldots,-1+\sum_{i=1}^c m_i\}$ (desired number of elements in the sample), $\vec{\omega}\in\mathbb{R}^c_{+}$ (weights/odds?) is:

$$p(\vec{x}) = \frac{1}{P_0} \prod_{i=1}^{c} \begin{pmatrix} m_i \\ x_i\end{pmatrix}\omega_i^{x_i}, \quad P_0 = \sum_{|\vec{y}| = n, 0\leq y_i \leq m_i} \prod_{j=1}^c \begin{pmatrix} m_j \\ y_j\end{pmatrix}\omega_j^{y_j}.$$

I am trying to understand how the above weights $\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_c$ are related to probabilities in practice. For simplicity let the number of elements per color be one ($m_i = 1)$, then $\vec{x} \in \{0,1\}^c$ and the probability mass function simplifies to:

$$p(\vec{x}) = \frac{1}{P_0} \prod_{i=1}^{c} \omega_i^{x_i}, \quad P_0 = \sum_{\vec{y} \in \{0,1\}^c,|\vec{y}| = n} \prod_{j=1}^c \omega_j^{y_j}.$$

My understanding is that the multivariate Fisher noncentral hypergeometric distribution models picking elements from an urn with a probability vector $\vec{q} \in [0,1]^c$, and considering outcomes as "valid" only if $|\vec{x}|= n$. Then I would expect the probability mass function for the case of $m_i=1$ to be given as (if we set $x_i = 1$ for $t\sim U[0,1]$ and $t<q_i$, and $x_i=0$ otherwise):

$$p(\vec{x}) = \frac{1}{Q_0} \prod_{i=1}^c \left(x_i q_i + (1-x_i)(1-q_i)\right), \quad Q_0 = \sum_{\vec{y}\in\{0,1\}^c, |\vec{y}|=n} \prod_{j=1}^c\left(y_j q_j + (1-y_j)(1-q_j)\right).$$

My question is how are $\vec{q}$ and $\vec{\omega}$ related? From the write up on the univariate case in wikipedia it seems that $\omega_i = \frac{q_i}{1-q_i}$, however I am not sure how one would get the correspondence between the two pmfs by just performing that change of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Using $q_i = \frac{\omega_i}{1+\omega_i}$, plugging into the probability mass function from my question:

$$p(\vec{x}) = \frac{1}{Q_0} \prod_{i=1}^c \left(x_i\frac{\omega_i}{1+\omega_i} + (1-x_i)\left(1-\frac{\omega_i}{1+\omega_i}\right)\right) = \frac{1}{Q_0}\prod_{i=1}^b\frac{1}{1+\omega_i}(x_i\omega_i+1-x_i) = \frac{\prod_{i=1}^c(1+\omega_i)^{-1}}{Q_0}\prod_{i=1}^c(x_i\omega_i+1-x_i) = \frac{1}{P_0}\prod_{i=1}^c\omega_i^{x_i}$$

In the last step I have used that $x_i \in \{0,1\}$.

In the general case ($m_i\geq 1$) I have the probability mass function:

$$p(\vec{x})=\frac{1}{Q_0}\prod_{i=1}^c \begin{pmatrix}m_i \\ x_i\end{pmatrix}q_i^{x_i}(1-q_i)^{m_i-x_i} = \frac{1}{Q_0}\prod_{i=1}^c\begin{pmatrix}m_i \\ x_i\end{pmatrix}\left(\frac{\omega_i}{1+\omega_i}\right)^{x_i}\left(\frac{1}{1+\omega_i}\right)^{m-x_i} \\ = \frac{\prod_{i=1}^c(1+\omega_i)^{-m_i}}{Q_0}\prod_{i=1}^c\begin{pmatrix}m_i \\ x_i\end{pmatrix}\omega_i^{x_i}$$

The probability for class $i$ the probability mass function resulting from the binomial distribution with $m_i$ trials, and probability of success $q_i$. Notably the term $\begin{pmatrix} m_i \\ x_i \end{pmatrix}$ is there because there are $\begin{pmatrix} m_i \\ x_i \end{pmatrix}$ ways of choosing $x_i$ elements from the $m_i$ elements of the class.